# Clarification on the MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database, join

I wanted to print the **nth maximum salary** from an employee table.

The query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp E1
WHERE
  (n-1) = (SELECT count(distinct(E2.salary))
           FROM emp E2 Where
           E2.salary< E1.salary)
ORDER BY
  E1.salary ASC
```

Though it worked good, I could not interpret how it works. Can anyone put some light on it?

Comment: i looks strange this `(n-1)` why is there

Comment: There are things missing here, the variable n for example.

Comment: it should be `n` instead of `n-1`

Comment: this will never work , i dont know how he said it works ,

Comment: As it stands it will return the nth lowest, not the nth highest salary records; otherwise, it should work.

Comment: i think that records are ranked already, so it might work... but it's strange anyway

Answer (score 2):

This a is feature in MYSQL.

If you have a basic query you can just use LIMIT

```
-- get the 9th highest salary
SELECT salary FROM tbl_salary
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 9,1
```

Incase if it is a complex query, you use

```
-- get the 9th highest salary
select distinct(salary) from tbl_salary e1
where 9 = (
select count(salary) 
from tbl_salary e2
where e1.salary< e2.salary
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly easier to understand as:

```
select * From emp E1 
where n = 1 + 
         (select count(distinct E2.salary) 
          from emp E2 
          Where E2.salary > E1.salary)
```

or:

```
select * From emp E1 
where n =(select count(distinct E2.salary) 
          from emp E2 
          Where E2.salary >= E1.salary)
```

For each record in the outer query, the subquery is returning a count of all distinct salary values on the same table that have a higher (or equal, in the second version) value; the equality condition in the outer query then ensures that only the records matching `n` numbers of higher salaries are selected.

The `order by` in the original query is unnecessary.